# Executing Tests in sequencial in testng

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I am executing a testng testsuite. I have one test in the testsuite. That test has a dataprovider which returns 2 records. so the same test has to run twice. I want these tests to run sequentially but what i see is it run parallely. I tried giving singleThread = true to the data provider but didnt work. I see following output

- BeforeMethod-1
- BeforeMothod-2
- Test-1
- Test-2
- AfterMethod-1
- AfterMethod-2

But what I want is

- BeforeMethod-1
- Test-1
- AfterMethod-1
- BeforeMothod-2
- Test-2
- AfterMethod-2

Comment: Split the 2 tests in 2 classes

Comment: it is same test with different parameters

Comment: What version of testng are you on.  For me it works the way you want.
DataProvider(name = "test2")
    public Object[][] createData2() {
        System.out.println("In dp ");
     return new Object[][] {
       { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
       { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
     };
    }
BeforeMethod
    public void befMet(){
sysout("Before");
    }
     
    Test(dataProvider = "test2")
    public void verifyData2(String n1, Integer n2) {
     sysout(n1 + " " + n2);
    }
    
    AfterMethod
    public void aftMet(){
        sysout("After");
    }

Comment: @ShrikanthKalluraya Do you have one or 2 before methods? Could you share the class?

Comment: @ShrikanthKalluraya Please the class instead the  where you have your current implementation.

Comment: ** @ShrikanthKalluraya Please share the class instead, where you have your current implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `parallel = true` from `DataProvider` method (getData) If specified.

```
@DataProvider()
```

Or

Make it **false**.

```
@DataProvider(parallel = false)
```

---

I tried the following example with `TestNG 6.8.5` with `default settings from Eclipse:`

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.asserts.Assertion;


public class TestExample {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(){
        System.out.println("before method ");
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void test1(String username, String password) {
        System.out.println("test");
        System.out.println("you have provided username as::"+username);
        System.out.println("you have provided password as::"+password);
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        System.out.println("after method");

    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
    //Rows - Number of times your test has to be repeated.
    //Columns - Number of parameters in test data.
    Object[][] data = new Object[2][2];

    // 1st row
    data[0][0] ="sampleuser1";
    data[0][1] = "abcdef";

    // 2nd row
    data[1][0] ="testuser2";
    data[1][1] = "zxcvb";

    return data;
    }

}
```

which gives me following output:

```
before method 
test
you have provided username as::sampleuser1
you have provided password as::abcdef
after method
before method 
test
you have provided username as::testuser2
you have provided password as::zxcvb
after method
PASSED: test1("sampleuser1", "abcdef")
PASSED: test1("testuser2", "zxcvb")

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Look what is the value defined for `dataproviderthreadcount` in .xml